Directory goes missing when piping basename from dirname
Given the folder structure
/recipes/foo/.env
/recipes/bar/.env

Running the following command:
find ./recipes -type f -name '.env' -print0 | xargs -0 dirname | xargs -0 basename

Output:
foo

Trimming the command down to:
find ./recipes -type f -name '.env' -print0 | xargs -0 dirname

Output:
./recipes/bar
./recipes/foo

So for some reason piping dirname to basename causes me to lose some of the found directories.

There are 2 issues here:

The -0 option of xargs indicates that the inputs are NUL-separated, not the outputs. In order to pipe the output of xargs -0 dirname to xargs -0 something you must use the -z option of dirname if it is supported (it is not POSIX). Else, its output is newline-separated.

basename does not support multiple arguments by default. If yours supports it (it is not POSIX) you can try -a or --multiple.
find ./recipes -type f -name '.env' -print0 |
  xargs -0 dirname -z | xargs -0 basename -a

Else, use the -n1 option of xargs:
find ./recipes -type f -name '.env' -print0 |
  xargs -0 dirname -z | xargs -0 -n1 basename



Note: as your find is apparently GNU find you could skip dirname with:
find ./recipes -type f -name '.env' -printf '%h\0' | xargs -0 basename -a

Note: you could also use only find and any POSIX shell:
find ./recipes -type f -name '.env' -exec sh -c '
d="${1%/*}"; printf "%s\n" "${d##*/}"' _ {} \;

Note: if, like in the example you show, the depth of the .env files is 2 you don't need find, xargs, dirname or basename. Your (POSIX) shell is enough (plus the printf utility if it is not already a built-in of your shell):
for f in recipes/*; do [ -f "$f/.env" ] && printf '%s\n' "${f##*/}"; done


or find ... -print0 | awk -vRS='\0' -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}'

@dave_thompson_085. Yes but as RS='\0' is not POSIX this requires GNU awk or another awk that supports it.

-print0 also isn't POSIX, and if you leave that out (and don't use newline in your pathnames, which only a crazy person does) POSIX awk's \n works

@dave_thompson_085 I fully agree with you Dave, and as the OP's find is apparently GNU find we can assume that their awk is also GNU. We can also assume that they don't have newlines in their pathnames. My personal position (you don't have to agree) is that not knowing who will read these Q&A and what they will do with it, I prefer trying to provide solutions that cannot break, even with low probability. And I am not saying that I always succeed. Just trying. So, if I had added your awk-based solution to my (already too long) answer, I would also have added GNU only.
